# Error in passing bytes32 data to a smart contract

Tags: solidity

I have a User Verification smart contract. I am generating an SHA-256 verification code for the users to be verified. I am accepting the verification code as `bytes32` in my smart contract. But when I try to test the function, I always see this error:

```
Error encoding arguments: SyntaxError: Unexpected token B in JSON at position 48
```

Here is the function:

```
function verify(bytes32 verification_code) public {
        if(user_verified[msg.sender] == false &&
            sha256(verification_code)==user_codes[msg.sender]){
                user_verified[msg.sender] = true;
            }
    }
```

I would appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Comment: This may be an issue related to javascript too. Please consider putting related code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 0x at the start of the SHA-256 verification code and pass the entire thing within `" "`.So, it will look something like `"0x..."`.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have tried but it did not work. Let me send you the error that I getting.

Comment: Here is the error: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid bytes32 value (arg="", type="string", value="B3B3886F389F27BC1F2A41F0ADD45A84453F0D2A877FCD1225F13CD95953A86A")

Comment: You have to add `0x` at beginning of your hash like `0xB3B3886F389F27BC1F2A41F0ADD45A84453F0D2A877FCD1225F13CD95953A86A` .

Comment: Tried that too. It throws the following error: Error encoding arguments: SyntaxError: Unexpected token x in JSON at position 48

Comment: i try "0xB3B3886F389F27BC1F2A41F0ADD45A84453F0D2A877FCD1225F13CD95953A86A" as input of bytes32 in my code and works successfully without any error. lets add a screenshot on my answer just check it.

Comment: It works. I have edited, upvoted, and accepted your answer. Thanks, @Mahesh Rajput!